# Trigonometric identity involving tan(A + B).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For the identitiy,

Sin(A + B) / cos(A + B) is the same (tanA + tanB)/ (1 - tanAtanB)

The closest I have come to reach the RHS,

Sin(A + B) = sinAcosB + sinBcosA

cos(A + B) = cosAcosB - sinAsinB

Sin(A + B) / cos(A + B) = ( sinAcosB + sinBcosA)/ (cosAcosB - sinAsinB)

I cannot move further to solve this identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the fact that $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}.$ If you start off from the RHS of the last identity you posted, we easily have

$\frac{\sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b} = \frac{\cos a \cos b(\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}+\frac{\sin b}{\cos b})}{\cos a \cos b(1-\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}\frac{\sin b}{\cos b})}=\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}$

Also, it's a good idea to use LaTeX when doing math over the internet, it makes the text much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite this quotient in the form $$\frac{\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)}{\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)}$$ and multiply numerator and demoninator by $$\frac{1}{\cos(A)\cos(B)}$$ and you will get
$$\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\tan(B)}$$